# Count the no of people who viewed a particular blog

Tags: 7

Is there any module that could count the no of people who viewed a particular blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would have to simply use to Statistic module that's there in the core. Enabling the module  would give you the view count of a node page.

In case if we want to track the activity of the user, we can use [Google Analytics](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the statistics module and using views module create a mini report. Other modules you could use in combination with the statistic module are [Visitors module](https://drupal.org/project/visitors) and [Counter module](https://drupal.org/project/counter)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics):

> Adds the Google Analytics web statistics tracking system to your website.